# Creating Adjacency List in Python using Dict and List

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary, graph

I wanted to create a data structure that can store the name of a vertex, vertices it is adjacent to along with the edge weight. I thought of creating a `dict` that maps a vertex to a `list` that further has `dict` to store vertices it is adjacent to with edge weight.

In other words:

```
D = {
    vertex1: [
        {
            Adj_vertex1: edge weight
        }, 
        {
            Adj_vertex2:    edge weight
        } 
    ]
}
```

Is there an effective way to do this? Also, if I use the structure above how do I access `Adj_vertex2`?

Comment: Why have a list of dicts and not just a dict : `D = {vertex1: {Adj_vertex1: weight, Adj_vertex2: weight}}` then access is as simple as `D[vertex1][Adj_vertex2]` but is more likely to be used in a loop `for a_v, w in D[vertex1].items():`

Comment: I could do that but is that the most effective I can be? Also, how do I extract weight of vertex2? by writing: D[vertex][vertex2]? I needed this data structure to first: access the vertices adjacent to vertex1, and second: to access the edge weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary works fine unless you have more complex structure. But you are declaring a list of dictionaries for your vertices. You can simplify it like this;

```
D = { vertex1: {Adj_vertex1: edge_weight, Adj_vertex2: edge_weight}}
```

And get adj_vertex2 weight like this;

```
D[vertex1][Adj_vertex2]
```

Or if you want to get a default value if a vertex is not adjacent to another, thus not exists in the dictionary you can use this (thanks to Hossein's comment):

```
D[vertex1].get(Adj_vertex2, 0)
```

And add a new vertex like this;

```
D[new_vertex] = {Adj_vertex1: edge_weight, Adj_vertex2: edge_weight}
```

Comment: Use `D[vertex1].get(vertex2,0)` to obtain `weight=0` if `vertex2` is not adjacent to `vertex1`

Comment: Thank you! But is this the effective method? The idea I had was just something that came to me first. I wanted to learn the effective way of creating something that can hold adjacent vertex and weight.

Comment: @BinamrataSharma I'm sure there are better ways (for readability and functionality) to represent this problem, dictionaries work in this case but for more check LaraChicharo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
d = {'vertex1': [ {'adj_vertex1': (edge, weight)}, {'adj_vertex2': (edge, weight)}]}
```

To access `adj_vertex2` you must do `d['vertex1'][1]['adj_vertex2']`

This is not a very good way to work with graphs in python in my opinion. You should check some libraries out like [python-graph](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-graph) or you could use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), sets are a good way to use graphs with python as far as I remember.

Note: `(this, is, a, tuple)`. On [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: Notice that I changed the name of the variables in your code, thats because they were not in line with pep-8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way that uses relatively standard tools would be to store adjacency as a sparse matrix. This would require you to use `scipy` and to number your vertices.

Assume you have the connected vertices as list of lists and the weights as another list of lists of the same structure

```
inds = [[1,3], [], [0,2], [0,2,3]]
weights = [[0.1,0.2], [], [1,1], [2,0.5,-0.1]]

adj = sparse.lil_matrix((4,4))
for i, (j, w) in enumerate(zip(inds, weights)):
    adj[i, j] = w

adj
# <4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 7 stored elements in LInked List format>
adj.A # dense representation
# array([[ 0. ,  0.1,  0. ,  0.2],
         [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
         [ 1. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ],
         [ 2. ,  0. ,  0.5, -0.1]])

adj = adj.tocsr() # convert to more efficient format

# get vertices connected to vertex 3:
adj[3].nonzero()[1]
# array([0, 2, 3], dtype=int32)

# get corresponding weights:
adj[3].data
# array([ 2. ,  0.5, -0.1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list of tuples to store the adjacencies and the weights makes more sense to me rather than storing it as dict. You can store it something like this,

```
    d = {
         'v1': [ ('v2',w1), ('v3', w2) ]
         'v2': [ ('v1', w1) ]
         'v3': [ ('v1', w2) ]
        }
```

Comment: What if I have to change the value of edge weight a I go along? Doesn't tuple refrain me from changing the value inside it?